# why doesn't my 4th intent button work?

Tags: android, button, android-intent

m i missing something? the first 3 work fine.

public void onClick(View v) {

```
switch (v.getId()) {
case R.id.hawknation_button:
   Intent i = new Intent(this, HawkNationRSS.class);
   startActivity(i);
   break;
   case R.id.hawkcentral_button:
   Intent i1 = new Intent(this, HawkCentralRSS.class);
   startActivity(i1);
   break; 
   case R.id.hawkeyesports_button:
       Intent i2 = new Intent(this, HawkeyeSportsRSS.class);
       startActivity(i2);
       break;    
   case R.id.espn_button:
       Intent i3 = new Intent(this, HawkeyeSportsRSS.class);
       startActivity(i3);
       break;


 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I should have done more digging before posting this. Forgot one critical line.

```
espn.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try finishing previous activity(ies) in each `case`. Maybe they are invoking(or returning to) `onResume()` since you are calling same class and they are separate activities.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as the third and fourth cases are in essence identical and you're saying the other three work, make sure that `R.id.espn_button` is indeed the correct resource ID, and that you've set the `onClick` handler for that button as well.